# Prefetch SBT versions, Scala, and Ivy Resources with SBT for creating an image

Tags: scala, sbt

I wish to create a docker image with several SBT components built in (docker part not relevant). If I just install sbt from deb or rpm and not do anything, the first time it is invoked it still has to download the internet before it's able to start.

Thus, I need to be able to specify the following:

1 SBT Versions - e.g. 0.12, 0.13.1, 0.13.2, ...

2 Scala Versions - 2.9.1, 2.10.4, 2.11.5, ...

3 Commonly used libraries - play framework, etc.

I'm wondering what's the best way to ensure those are already pre-cached.

Comment: Even with the answer, I'm *still* confused with what you're up to. Why do you need `sbt` on the docker image? When you execute sbt outside a project, it's going to download the default dependencies to run (you actually install `sbt-launcher` that's going to launch `sbt`). Do you need `sbt` for anything outside projects?

Comment: I'm building an image for a custom deploy `drone.io`. Using the default image for drone with sbt in it works fine, but takes a very long time to build due to it fetching the version of `sbt` currently used, scala versions, and dependencies. I wish to cut this down significantly.

Comment: There is a problem with Scala and the way it interacts with the Docker eco system. Scala wants SBT to do the building/running. The slow builds and masses of dependences are problematic.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I do in my Dockerfile to prefetch multiple scala versions :

```
RUN echo 'crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.6", "2.11.7")' > build.sbt \
    && echo 'object Hi { def main(args: Array[String]) = println("Done") }' > src.scala \
    && sbt "+run" \
    && rm build.sbt src.scala
```

You can easily customize this further by specifying the sbt version on cli ( sbt -Dsbt.version=0.x.y "+run" ), or add some libraryDependencies to the build.sbt.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you create one project which has everything you want listed as dependency -- including SBT and Scala versions, and then run `update` to retrieve all these dependencies, they'll all be cached on `.ivy2\cache`. This should serve for pretty much everything, but SBT itself seems to have tons of separate dependencies as seen [here](https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/), or on your local disk at the ivy2 cache.